# Why does is div not visible after clicking button?

Tags: javascript

My div does not seem to appear after clicking the button that removes the 'hidden' class from it,  in js.

I tried clicking the button expecting to see the 'Planner' screen but page turned blank instead.

Below are my codes in js and html

HTML:

```html
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-lg-planno" id="themeSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" >
<!-- planner -->
<div id="plannerWin">
    <div class="planner hidden" id="plannerWindow">
        <p id="headerText2">
            <svg id="svgStyle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="978" height="74" viewBox="0 0 978 74"><g transform="translate(-1613 -1760)"><line x2="862" transform="translate(1666.5 1819.5)" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"/><circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(1652 1805)" fill="#b5b5b5"/><circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(1805 1805)" fill="#b5b5b5"/><circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(1992 1805)" fill="#b5b5b5"/><circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(2181 1805)" fill="#b5b5b5"/><g transform="translate(2339 1805)" fill="#efeded" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="1"><circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" stroke="none"/><circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14" fill="none"/></g><circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" transform="translate(2514 1805)" fill="#b5b5b5"/><g transform="translate(1626 1838)"><text transform="translate(40 -64)" fill="#b5b5b5" font-size="15" font-family="Suissnord" letter-spacing="0.05em"><tspan x="-52.018" y="0">Monthly</tspan><tspan x="-37.308" y="19">Tasks</tspan></text></g><g transform="translate(1779 1838)"><text transform="translate(40 -64)" fill="#b5b5b5" font-size="15" font-family="Suissnord" letter-spacing="0.05em"><tspan x="-38.572" y="0">THEME</tspan></text></g><g transform="translate(1964 1838)"><text transform="translate(40 -64)" fill="#b5b5b5" font-size="15" font-family="Suissnord" letter-spacing="0.05em"><tspan x="-84.313" y="0">TEMPERATURE</tspan><tspan x="-52.454" y="19">RECORDS</tspan></text></g><g transform="translate(2155 1838)"><text transform="translate(40 -64)" fill="#b5b5b5" font-size="15" font-family="Suissnord" letter-spacing="0.05em"><tspan x="-45.121" y="0">WEEKLY</tspan><tspan x="-36.957" y="19">TASKS</tspan></text></g><g transform="translate(2313 1838)"><text transform="translate(40 -64)" font-size="15" font-family="Suissnord" letter-spacing="0.05em"><tspan x="-51.45" y="0">PLANNER</tspan></text></g><g transform="translate(2488 1838)"><text transform="translate(40 -64)" fill="#b5b5b5" font-size="15" font-family="Suissnord" letter-spacing="0.05em"><tspan x="-62.471" y="0">HANDOVER</tspan><tspan x="-37.938" y="19">NOTES</tspan></text></g></g></svg>
        </p>
        <p class="headerText">Planner</p>
        <textarea rows="5" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-lg-handover" id="themeSubmit" type="submit" value="Save">
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ml-3" id="themeSubmit" type="submit" value="Skip">
        <img src="svg/back.svg" id="back">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const planner = document.querySelector('.planner');
const btnPlanner = document.querySelector('.btn-lg-planno');


// Planner Activate
btnPlanner.addEventListener('click', function () {
    weeklyT.classList.add('hidden'); 
    planner.classList.remove('hidden');        
});
```

Comment: You don't show us what the `weeklyT` variable is. Did you write this code? Are you hiding some wrapping parent element stored in `weeklyT` which hides the entire page?

Comment: JS ---> const weeklyT = document.querySelector('.weekly-tasks');

Comment: <!-- Weekly Tasks -->
            <div id="weekly">
                <div class="weekly-tasks hidden" id="weeklyTasks">
                    <p id="headerText2">

Comment: dunno if that answers your question. i wrote the code, i'm a beginner in js hence the confusion, apologies. 'Weekly Tasks' is a section and a child of a parent div container

Comment: Please don't post information in comments, remove the comments and edit the question to include more detail. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well, especially how to create a "Minimal, Reproducible Example". Right now you might be asking about code you're not showing us (`weeklyT`), or there could be Javascript errors you're ignoring